# API Platform - Server Push problem with Vulcain

Tags: http2, api-platform.com

I'm trying to demonstrate to my team that Vulcain/HTTP\2 is better than GraphQL, but I don't have Server Push ... I don't understand why ...

I have no error in Docker's logs and I could not find the solution, I took as example this project https://github.com/dunglas/demo-vulcain-api-platform

In chrome's devtools I do not see any difference between

```
const conferences = await fetchJson ('/conferences', {headers: {Preload: '/hydra:member/*/@id/sessions/*/feedback/*'}});
```

and

```
const conferences = await fetchJson ('/conferences');
```

script: https://github.com/dunglas/demo-vulcain-api-platform/blob/master/api/public/test-min-waterfall.html

There's got to be something I'm doing wrong, but I don't know what?

What actions are required to make Vulcain work with API Platform?

In the Docker's logs Vulcain is ok, in Chrome I see that the protocol is "h2", but Chrome not receiving Push from the Server...

Docker's logs from Vulcain:

```
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:04 +0000] "GET /test.html HTTP/2.0" 200 491 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences HTTP/2.0" 200 694 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0" 200 6915 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/9 HTTP/2.0" 200 162 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/10 HTTP/2.0" 200 179 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/1 HTTP/2.0" 200 171 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/8 HTTP/2.0" 200 171 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/7 HTTP/2.0" 200 158 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/6 HTTP/2.0" 200 167 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/5 HTTP/2.0" 200 169 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/3 HTTP/2.0" 200 159 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/4 HTTP/2.0" 200 163 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/4 HTTP/2.0" 200 248 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /conferences/2 HTTP/2.0" 200 173 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/15 HTTP/2.0" 200 269 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/31 HTTP/2.0" 200 267 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/38 HTTP/2.0" 200 280 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/97 HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/52 HTTP/2.0" 200 254 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/73 HTTP/2.0" 200 264 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/98 HTTP/2.0" 200 281 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/2 HTTP/2.0" 200 255 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/50 HTTP/2.0" 200 268 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/17 HTTP/2.0" 200 261 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/30 HTTP/2.0" 200 264 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/9 HTTP/2.0" 200 246 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/26 HTTP/2.0" 200 248 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/14 HTTP/2.0" 200 263 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/44 HTTP/2.0" 200 256 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/71 HTTP/2.0" 200 269 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/80 HTTP/2.0" 200 250 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/96 HTTP/2.0" 200 263 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/89 HTTP/2.0" 200 267 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/24 HTTP/2.0" 200 275 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/74 HTTP/2.0" 200 240 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/8 HTTP/2.0" 200 264 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/13 HTTP/2.0" 200 239 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/11 HTTP/2.0" 200 273 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/6 HTTP/2.0" 200 245 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/81 HTTP/2.0" 200 260 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/55 HTTP/2.0" 200 272 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/84 HTTP/2.0" 200 260 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/87 HTTP/2.0" 200 281 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/78 HTTP/2.0" 200 232 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/82 HTTP/2.0" 200 279 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/10 HTTP/2.0" 200 279 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/12 HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/21 HTTP/2.0" 200 270 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/59 HTTP/2.0" 200 250 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/94 HTTP/2.0" 200 245 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/61 HTTP/2.0" 200 281 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/25 HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/32 HTTP/2.0" 200 282 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/88 HTTP/2.0" 200 264 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/36 HTTP/2.0" 200 260 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/51 HTTP/2.0" 200 277 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/67 HTTP/2.0" 200 267 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/69 HTTP/2.0" 200 256 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/49 HTTP/2.0" 200 267 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/7 HTTP/2.0" 200 264 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/39 HTTP/2.0" 200 252 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/91 HTTP/2.0" 200 251 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/72 HTTP/2.0" 200 266 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/77 HTTP/2.0" 200 261 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/54 HTTP/2.0" 200 253 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/16 HTTP/2.0" 200 273 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/29 HTTP/2.0" 200 286 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/37 HTTP/2.0" 200 296 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/5 HTTP/2.0" 200 239 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/95 HTTP/2.0" 200 289 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/90 HTTP/2.0" 200 257 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/100 HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/66 HTTP/2.0" 200 247 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/83 HTTP/2.0" 200 276 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/1 HTTP/2.0" 200 281 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/18 HTTP/2.0" 200 256 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/46 HTTP/2.0" 200 263 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/60 HTTP/2.0" 200 266 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/47 HTTP/2.0" 200 284 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/35 HTTP/2.0" 200 255 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/57 HTTP/2.0" 200 271 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/99 HTTP/2.0" 200 259 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/70 HTTP/2.0" 200 269 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/68 HTTP/2.0" 200 238 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/42 HTTP/2.0" 200 251 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/19 HTTP/2.0" 200 271 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/63 HTTP/2.0" 200 262 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/22 HTTP/2.0" 200 280 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/34 HTTP/2.0" 200 235 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/41 HTTP/2.0" 200 272 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/56 HTTP/2.0" 200 243 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/3 HTTP/2.0" 200 244 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/43 HTTP/2.0" 200 289 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/33 HTTP/2.0" 200 286 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/27 HTTP/2.0" 200 242 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/23 HTTP/2.0" 200 269 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/58 HTTP/2.0" 200 250 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/75 HTTP/2.0" 200 271 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/62 HTTP/2.0" 200 232 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/92 HTTP/2.0" 200 258 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /feedback/2 HTTP/2.0" 200 229 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/20 HTTP/2.0" 200 258 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/40 HTTP/2.0" 200 275 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/28 HTTP/2.0" 200 242 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/48 HTTP/2.0" 200 274 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/45 HTTP/2.0" 200 273 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/53 HTTP/2.0" 200 273 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/64 HTTP/2.0" 200 277 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/65 HTTP/2.0" 200 263 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/93 HTTP/2.0" 200 265 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/79 HTTP/2.0" 200 244 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /sessions/85 HTTP/2.0" 200 284 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"
vulcain_1  | 172.24.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2020:14:46:05 +0000] "GET /feedback/78 HTTP/2.0" 200 206 "https://localhost:8443/test.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36"...
```

[Network Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgv2r.jpg)

Can you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Server push or preloading ? Did you configure your entities to [push their associations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/push-relations/) ?

Comment: @rugolinifr , configure entities to push their associations, was not exactly what I was looking for.
I want the client to give the "preload" and the server push the resources.
My problem is that I don't have the push...

Comment: I can't help you more, I don't use vulcain myself. Purpose of my previous comment was just to force server push to see if you notice something either in the API or in the network tab. You may try to ask on [slack](https://symfony-devs.slack.com/join/shared_invite/zt-j364b7wk-VlNsKjEive9xayG1ksLh9w#/).

Comment: @rugolinifr When I use @ApiProperty(push=true) it's ok, thanks anyway

Comment: I just posted an updated procedure to test Vulcain+Caddy there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76056671/how-to-use-vulcain-caddy-module-with-api-platform -> the issue is still present...