# How to use Vulcain caddy module with API Platform?

Tags: php, api-platform.com, caddy

I've been trying for a long time to set up Vulcain with Api Pltform without success. I have the feeling that it is more a Vulain issue as I never found how to make it work through Caddy module.

Here are my steps to reproduce the issue (inspired from the outdated Vulcain+API Platform demo [here](https://github.com/dunglas/demo-vulcain-api-platform)):

Download Api Platform v3.0.9 release

```bash
curl -L https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/archive/refs/tags/v3.0.9.tar.gz
tar xzvf v3.0.9.tar.gz
cd api-platform-3.0.9
```

Fix PNPM issue as stated here: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/2417

Configure the API to be Fully Normalized

```yaml
# api/config/packages/api_platform.yaml
api_platform:
    defaults:
        normalization_context:
            iri_only: true
    # ...
```

Start the app

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

Create entites like here https://github.com/dunglas/demo-vulcain-api-platform

Update schema + load fixtures :

```
docker compose exec php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
docker compose exec php composer req --dev alice
```

```yaml
# api/fixtures/data.yaml
App\Entity\Conference:
    conference_{1..10}:
        name: '<catchPhrase()>'

App\Entity\Session:
    session_{1..100}:
        conference: '@conference_*'
        title: '<catchPhrase()>'
        summary: '<sentences(3, true)>'
        author: '<name()>'

App\Entity\Feedback:
    feedback_{1..100}:
        session: '@session_*'
        comment: '<sentences(3, true)>'
        rating: '<numberBetween(0, 5)>'
```

```
docker compose exec php bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load
```

Try with this code: (inspired from the demo)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Maximum waterfall: API Platform X Vulcain</title>
<script>
  async function fetchJson(url, opts = {}) {
    const resp = await fetch(url, opts);
    return resp.json();
  }

  (async function() {
// Load ALL data from the API
    console.time('download');
    const conferences = await fetchJson('/conferences', { headers: { Preload: '/hydra:member/*/sessions/*/feedback/*' }});
    // const conferences = await fetchJson('/conferences');

    // Fetch conferences
    conferences['hydra:member'].forEach(async conferenceRel => {
      const conference = await fetchJson(conferenceRel);

      // Fetch sessions
      conference.sessions.forEach(async sessionURL => {
        const session = await fetchJson(sessionURL);

        // Fetch feedback
        session.feedback.forEach(async feedbackURL => {
          const feedback = await fetchJson(feedbackURL);
        })
      })
    })
    console.timeEnd('download');
  })();
</script>
```

With Slow 3G throttling + Disable cache in Chrom DevTools I get the the cascade profile like here on the left where I should get the right profile:
[image]

Is there anything more to do to enable Vulcain?